# Creating Localization Files for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization

I would like to localize one of my apps.  But I just CANNOT seem to figure it out.  I have tried to read apple's docs, and I have looked at a bunch of tutorials that I found by searching.  I understand how to change all my strings to `NSLocalizedStrings`, and how to edit those localized files one there created, but my problem is I can't figure out how to create those directories in the first place.

How do you make those folders `en.lproj` and a spanish one.  Also, how do you make the two string files that go inside them.

Step by step help would be greatly appreciated, or a link to a detailed tutorial on this part.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I've made countless attempts and an simply stuck.

Comment: Here is a step by step tutorial: [How To Internationalize an OS X/iOS App](http://www.delitestudio.com/2012/09/11/how-to-internationalize-an-os-x-ios-app/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When selecting a file, in the Utility sidebar you will see the localization panel.
There you can add languages.

Comment: Xcode 4. For Xcode 3 you just need to go to the project preferences (project file -> get info) and there you can add languages (somewhere at the first tab I think).

Comment: Great that helped, but it created localized files for each class.  Is this any way to just create a file of localized strings, rather than 2 copies of the same class

Answer (score 13):

you are nearly done with doing `NSLocalizedStrings`. You open up terminal.app and change the dir to your project by changing dir. Type in `cd` and drop in your project folder. Then tipe in: `genstrings ./Classes/*.m`this will create a file with all strings you entered. Look in your project folder for `Localizable.strings` and drag it into Xcode project. Uncheck the box that says "copy into destination group..." and change the text encoding to **UTF-16**! Then open the info window for that file and check "Make file localizable", switch to general tab and enter for ex: `fr` for the new localization and click add. Now you can change the localization to french, where it says `fr` (or whatever you have)

Comment: You offered great insight into this. I didn't know I could generate the strings files using a Terminal command. That would have saved me a lot of time had I known this a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Xcode 4.4 and up you have to go to the Project Info and add all the languages there, you can't add languages from any file info