# How can I share my iPhone app for translators?

Tags: iphone, ios, translate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating Localization Files for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687339/creating-localization-files-for-ios)

i have my iPhone company app in English language and we are international company, so how can I share my App for all translators f.e. by simulator or something else ?

f.e. translator  translate the text and need view effect on iPhone, how can I do this?

Comment: for distribution to limited audience look here : http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/  , though it won't help you much with localization

Answer (score 0):

You can look at incorporating the [Greenwich framework](http://fadingred.github.com/greenwich/) into your app. I've not used it myself, but saw it demo'd at a conference recently. It will let the translators make the changes to the app that you distribute to them as an ad-hoc build and then see them running in your app.